# jQuery Mobile + FullCalendar - need to refresh page to see it with multiple page divs

Tags: jquery-mobile, fullcalendar

[Please see this jsbin test page that illustrates the issue](http://jsbin.com/zanalu/1/edit?html,js,output)

I have a simple jqm page with two page divs. The only initialization is being done inside a $(document).on('pageshow', function(){}); block. Inside the block, I initialize a fullcalendar.js calendar.

If I load the page as an external page (the first link in the menu) it loads without a hitch (but it's not using ajax, so the page flickers and there's no transition).

If I load the page using the jqm convention of linking to the id of the second page div with an anchor tag, it loads the calendar div as a page with no data.

If I then refresh the page, the data is displayed. Subsequent use of the menu displays both page divs as pages without issue.

I've seen a lot of discussion about which event of the pagecontainer widget to use, and I'm aware that document.ready() is not the way to go. I've tried all the possibilities, I think (pagebeforeshow, pageshow, pageinit, etc.) There's more detail in the demo, where you can see all the code. If I need to post it here, too, I can do that, but it's easier to see the issue if you load the test at jsbin. I suggest running it in a separate window, so you can refresh the page.

If anyone else has solved this or has an idea what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate the help and / or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I put all of the pagecontainer events into my test jsbin code and stepped through them. (Thanks to Gajotres for providing useful documentation on the various pagecontainer hooks). It turns out that the one I needed was 'pagecontainerhide' instead of pageshow, pageinit, or any of the others. Once I modified the code to use that event, the calendar displayed properly on the page div, with transition, and I no longer had to click on refresh to see load the "page".

Since I have all the events there, perhaps others with page change issues can benefit from the test page....